# Is Analytic Continuation possible if we assume real analytic function?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, analytic-functions

I come across proof of analytic continuation.
As follows[image]

[image]

In this theorem Author uses only analytic property i.e existence of power series around some point.

I was thinking if in case of real function if we have such function i.e which has power series exapansion then it should posses analytical continution.

IS my right /Or where I am Missing?
ANy Help will be appreciated
Any Help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is true for analytic functions. Whether we're working over the real numbers or over the complex numbers is irrelevant.

However, this has nothing to do with [analytic continuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation). The statement that we are talking about here is the [identity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem).